# What is the blessed way to link two (2) relay chains

Tags: parachain, relay-chain

I'm guessing by placing a parachain between them?

But that begs the question: Can one parachain join/belong to two relay chains?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the use case you are trying? Can this be done with a Bridge:  https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-bridges

Comment: Thanks, for a use case think public-private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long term bridges seem the right way: [bridge pallets](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-bridges#via-bridge-pallets)

In fact right now the [testing document](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/blob/master/docs/testing-scenarios.md#testing-scenarios) deals with a Polkadot-Kusama bridge.

The code is currently under heavy development, but there are some [docs](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/blob/master/docs/high-level-overview.md) and there are nine (9) [relay clients](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/tree/master/relays) implemented at this time.